# Google App Engine/Managed VM Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform, google-managed-vm

We're currently running on App Engine (Java) and want to test the new managed VMs that Google are beta testing.

Everything builds, but I can't get any of the endpoints to work.

When I build, the error that comes back is:

> SEVERE: Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an
>   error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate
>   with it.

In the admin logs I can see that it has attempted, but the error comes back:

> API configuration update failed

The discovery docs get created locally, but there isn't anything in the logs. 
I can see the POST to the getApiConfigs, but no details on the failure.

Hopefully someone else has encountered the same problem and can help?

In essence my question is, what do I need to do to get cloud endpoints running on a managed VM for App Engine?

Thanks

Comment: If you would file a bug at the [external tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) with label Component=Endpoints and your app id, I can help debug.

Comment: thanks @saiyr, it turned out to be a custom filter that was preventing the API from being generated.
Out of interest, do you know when managed VMs will be available in the EU?

Comment: @saiyr Are Cloud Endpoints supported on Managed VMs? I have been informed 2 times that they are not...

Comment: No, they are not officially supported, but they should still work mostly. They should be better supported in coming months.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer ?
I had the same problem and after checking the logs I realized that I had two classes with the same API name and version but one had namespace and the other didn't.

All API classes with the same API name and version must have the exact same API-wide configuration.

I just set the namespace to be the same for both API's and it worked.