# Appengine api explorer doesn't send queries to localhost

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to use google api explorer on my local machine, so I visit developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api#p/.
I have already made it show list of functions (it works only in firefox, with protection disabled, as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36393144/8738724), but when I press the Execute button, it sends the request to appspot: GET https://my-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/conference/v1/profile instead of http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/conference/v1/profile. This isn't the correct behaviour, I guess. Does anyone know how to make it send requests to my local machine? I thought this is what "base=http://localhost:8080" is all about!

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that worked for me is to allow the Chrome to load unsafe script, see details [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?p=unauthenticated&visit_id=1-636558629257614075-3360078989&rd=1#content). I tested with a Windows VM and latest version of Chrome. The steps are:

1. Run locally an API. In my case I followed this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python#before-you-begin) until Running the sample locally section
2. Browse to the URL [developers.google.com/apis-explorer/base=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api#p/](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api#p/)
3. Allow Chrome to load unsafe script by click the shell sign at right of URL bar.

[image]

These are the results:

API explorer:
[image]

Log:
[image]

Then I tested with one of the methods and everything worked correctly for me.

API explorer:
[image]

Log:
[image]

Hope this will help you.